# split string on numeric/non-numeric boundary

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string into a list (Python) where each segment is either wholly numeric or wholly non-numeric

Examples;

- `'100.200.300'` gives `['100', '.', '200', '.', '300']`
- `'abc0foo!bar'` gives `['abc', '0', 'foo!bar']`
- `'123'` gives `['123']`
- `'foo'` gives `['foo']`

The input might start or end with either a numeric part or non-numeric part. The result, when joined on `""` must reproduce the original input in full.

If I split on e.g. `\d+` then I will keep the non-numeric parts and lose the numeric parts. I can loop on `^(\d+|\D+)(.*)$` but that's annoying.

Can I (in a single expression) split on the boundary and keep all the string parts and non-string parts in the resulting list?

Comment: `re.findall(r'\d+|\D+')` works as intended for every example you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combination of positive lookahead & lookbehind in regex to determine the boundaries(delimiters) around which you can split the given string. Use:

```
import re

matches = re.split(r'(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)', string)
```

The resulting `matches` for the given strings will be,

```
['abc', '0', 'foo!bar'] # 'abc0foo!bar'
['100', '.', '200', '.', '300'] # '100.200.300'
['123'] # '123'
['foo'] # 'foo'
```

*Explanation:*

1. *Positive Lookbehind `(?<=\D)`*

   - `\D` matches any character that's not a digit.
2. *Positive Lookahead `(?=\d)`*

   - `\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
3. *Positive Lookbehind `(?<=\d)`*

   - `\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
4. *Positive Lookahead `(?=\D)`*

   - `\D` matches any character that's not a digit.

You can test the regular expression [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/sJvut8/1).